# Python loop through group elements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe object in the following format:

```
    _id      botId   id   sessionId    timestamp      intentStatus  
0   5ba2a04   tony  9336  asdg23eas  1537385724842     NotHandled  
1   5babb04   tony  0434  bbdg23eas  1537385722365      Handled
2   6ba2a04   tony  7336  bbdg23eas  1537385932445     NotHandled  
3   7babb04   tony  0454  asdg23eas  1537385038234      Handled
```

I want to group the above dataframe by sessionId, then find the timedifference of each group's last element timestamp and first element timestamp. So far, I was able to do this much:

```
    groupBySession = df.groupby('sessionId')
    for name, group in groupBySession:
        group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The problem with the above approach is that I cant loop within the individual groups created because the index is not reset. From the above code, I'm getting groups in the following format:

**First Group**

```
     _id        botId   id  sessionId   timestamp       intentStatus  
  0 5ba2a04     tony   9336 asdg23eas  1537385724842     NotHandled
  1 7babb04     tony   0454 asdg23eas  1537385724842     NotHandled
```

**Second Group**

```
     _id        botId   id  sessionId   timestamp       intentStatus  
  0 5babb04     tony   0434 bbdg23eas  1537385722365      Handled
  1 6ba2a04     tony   7336 bbdg23eas  1537385932445     NotHandled
```

If you notice, the index is getting replaced and is starting from 0. But, when I try to print the second groups first elements first element as

```
print(group[0])
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Is there something that Im doing wrong or missing? And is there a better approach to implement this?

Comment: those are individual dataframes, you can see the type of groups , just use loc in printing row

Comment: `group` holds a dataframe now, which does not have a column `0`

Comment: Use `loc`: `group.loc[0,:]`

Comment: Are you after `df.groupby('sessionId')['timestamp'].apply(lambda L: L.iloc[-1] - L.iloc[0])` ?

Comment: @RafaelC, can you explain a bit more? Im very new to python. My requirement is, after getting the groups, I want to find the difference between the timestamp of the last element and the timestamp of the first element

Comment: Do you need to worry about the rows of your data frame getting shuffled?  If you are looking for the difference between the smallest and largest timestamp for each `sessionId` you might want to consider   `df.groupby('sessionId').apply(lambda x: x.timestamp.max() - x.timestamp.min())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through a groupby and then individual rows of each group:

```
for name, group in groupBySession:
   for index, row in group.iterrows():
       row['whtevr col']
```